# I have issue in importing project in Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

When I import a project from any other external folder, it saves in a "java" folder and not in "src". "src" folder is empty. How to solve this?

Every time I need to create a java file, copy the code and doing. Since it takes more time for some project which has so many java files. How to rectify this?

I am attaching screenshot. I marked as red line where you can see imported project which saves in java folder.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the `java` folder then click

```
Build Path > Use as a Source Folder
```